# How to run multiple linear models at once

Tags: r

I am now to R programming. I want to run 100 linear models at once with same independent variables but with different dependent variables like

```
lm1<-lm(y1~x1+x2+x3)
lm2<-lm(y2~x1+x2+x3)
lm3<-lm(y3~x1+x2+x3)
```

and so on.

Please help me run all these linear models at once. And also tell me how to generate constant and their `t` values at once for all models.

Plz help otherwise I have to run every model individually. Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider parallel processing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754412/how-to-do-parallel-in-r?rq=1

Comment: You can use multiple regression and get all the coefficients in one model: `lm(cbind(y1,y2,y3)~x1+x2+x3)`

Comment: Follow @Rohit's advice. It's the most efficient approach.

Comment: Tnx Rohit Sir for a wonderful advice

Comment: @Rohit Rohit Sir If have two data frames. One as variables of dependent and one independent. I want to run linear models such as lm1<-lm(df1$y1~df2$x1), lm2(df1$x2~df2$y2) and so on. How can i do this

Answer (score 1):

You can parse a vector of outcome variables in `lapply()` using `as.formula()` to paste everything together:

```
lapply(
  c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), # outcomes
  function(x) lm(as.formula(paste(x, "~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species")), data = iris))
```

`lapply()` can be parallelised fairly easily for a performance boost.

Comment: Tnx Paul Sir but it does not work on xts and zoo class. It will work on df only

Comment: Tnx very much paul sir

Comment: If you feel like this solves your problem, please up and accept my answer. Happy to help.

Comment: Paul Sir If have two data frames. One as variables of dependent and one independent. I want to run linear models such as lm1<-lm(df1$y1~df2$x1), lm2(df1$x2~df2$y2) and so on. How can i do this

Comment: You would need to join/bind them into a single data frame.